# How to chain synchronous request without refreshing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Firstly, I am loading user data from a remote endpoint with `componentDidMount` and setting state in this method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
      .then(res => {
        const users = res.data.map(obj => obj);
        this.setState({ data: users });
      })
}
```

Then I am adding a user with POST request to an API and I want to load new user data from a remote endpoint and setting state again in order to see new addition displayed:

```
addUser = () => {
  var currentThis = this;
  axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/api/users", {

        Name: this.Name.inputRef.value,
        Surname: this.Surname.inputRef.value,
      })
      .then(res => {
        const status = res.data.status;
        if (status === 'OK'){
          axios
           .get("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
           .then(res => {
             const users = res.data.map(obj => obj);
             currentThis.setState({ data: users });
           })
        }
        else{
          //error
        }
      })
}
```

Request in callback `.then` function always responds the users before posting new user. So state doesn't change and I have to reload the page to display new addition.

How can I update or render the respond without reloading the page?

Comment: did you mean *asynchronous* in the title?

Comment: No, I mean synchronous. So GET request in callback must occur after the POST request completed. It must be queue. Asynchronous request may be disrupting

Comment: GET will occur after POST, because you've coded correctly for asynchronous nature of POST, so, not sure what your question actaully is

Comment: If I tried to add a new user with POST. GET must respond with new addition but newly added does not return. So, state is not updating until refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the callback of the setState() to make the second AJAX request?  Something like this:

```
addUser = () => {
  var currentThis = this;
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/api/users", {
      Name: this.Name.inputRef.value,
      Surname: this.Surname.inputRef.value,
    })
    .then(res => {
      const status = res.data.status;
      if (status === 'OK'){
        const users = res.data.map(obj => obj);
        currentThis.setState({ data: users }, function() {
            axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
          }
        });
      else{
        //error
      }
    })
}
```

[More info on the setState() function and its callback param](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: I am already using the callback to make the second request. I did not notice any difference

Comment: Here I am referring to the callback of the setState function, not the resolver for the first axios POST request.  In your code, you are calling `currentThis.setState({ data: users });` with just 1 parameter (the new state of the component).  Are you aware you can pass a second parameter to the setState() function which is a callback function which executes after the component has updated with the new state?

Comment: It makes more sense now, but I tried it, state has not updated with the new state. Callback still responds previous user list. So interesting

Answer (score 0):

If you are the author of those APIs, you should make it such that on successful POST request, return the updated user list or the new user itself. Then you can just `setState` using the response.

If you don't have controls over the APIs, and since you're assure that `status === 'OK'` means new user has been added, why do you need to make another GET request?

Simply add the newly created object to your `data` state, then setState:

```
if (status === 'OK'){
  const updatedUsers = this.state.data.push(newUser)
  this.setState({data: updatedUsers})
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm author of the APIs, but these are not solution, because you just add the new user to the state. Data must store whole user list. Yes I can return all users in response of POST request. But It doesn't make sense.

Comment: why do you need to make another GET request?
to display users dynamically without reload page